# Why is the output of the maximum of two string literals wrong?

Tags: c++, templates, string-literals

Can someone explain, why the output is "C" in this code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class X>
X maximum(X a,X b)
{
    if(a > b)
        return a;
    else 
        return b;
}

int main() {
    cout << maximum("C","D") << endl;
}
```

Comment: lexicographical comparison is happening here.

Comment: @BuildSucceeded no, it's not. It's just comparing 2 unrelated pointers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that in your case the type `X` will be inferred as `const char*`, hence you are comparing two `const char *`s i.e. the addresses of the two string literals.

If you want to get the expected result, use something like the following

```cpp
cout << maximum("C"sv, "D"sv) << endl;
// or
cout << maximum<string_view>("C", "D") << endl;
```

This compares two `std::string_view`s, which is a lexicographical comparison, not a pointer comparison.

See [`std::string_view` comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator_cmp), and see [demo at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fGjxen574).

Alternatively, use characters instead of using string literals i.e `'C'` and `'D'`. In that case, `X` will be deduced to `char`.

---

See also [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `maximum("C","D")`, the template parameter is `char const*`. You end up comparing two pointers. There is no guarantee which pointer will be greater. You have indeterminate behavior.

If you want to compare the string `"C"` and string `"D"`, you can use:

```
cout << maximum(std::string("C"), std::string("D")) << endl; // or
cout << maximum("C"s, "D"s) << endl;                         // or
cout << maximum<std::string>("C", "D");
```

If you want compare just the characters `C` and `D`, you should use

```
cout << maximum('C', 'D') << endl;
```

Comment: or 'C' and 'D' if author wanted to compare just chars

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk, indeed.

Comment: For comparing string literals, consider using `maximum<std::string>(“C”, “D”)`, or `maximum(“C”s, “D”s)` like in asmmo’s answer.

Comment: *unspecified behaviour

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work for cstring-literals also, add overloads.

```cpp
#include <cstring>

template<class X>
X maximum(X a, X b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b; 
}

char const* maximum(char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(a, b) > 0 ? a : b;
}

char* maximum(char* a, char* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(a, b) > 0 ? a : b;
}
```